# Order multidimentional array with cakephp find all

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have Story related to a Chapter with a many to many relation 
I have a StoryChapter Model .

I have this find all stories result :

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Story' => array(
        'id' => '111',
        'title' => 'First Story',
        'question' => 'What do you want ?',
        'description' => 'ezrsrfgq ergtqergq',
        'date' => '2014-06-10',
        'image' => '/uploads/stories/111.jpg',
        'created' => '2014-06-10 07:51:35',
        'modified' => '2014-06-13 12:45:43',
        'created_by' => '1',
        'original' => null,
        'tags' => ''
    ),
    'StoryChapter' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '110',
            'story_id' => '111',
            'chapter_id' => '81',
            'chapter_title' => 'Second Chapter',
            'created' => '2014-06-11 00:00:00'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '109',
            'story_id' => '111',
            'chapter_id' => '80',
            'chapter_title' => 'First Chapter',
            'created' => '2014-06-13 00:00:00'
        )
    ),
    'StoryUser' => array(),
    'StoryGroup' => array(),
    'Favorite' => array(),
    'Tag' => array()
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Story' => array(
        'id' => '112',
        'title' => 'Second Story',
        'question' => 'What do you want ?',
        'description' => 'edghs rthsghsx ghs rhsgrhsrtgh',
        'date' => '2014-06-13',
        'image' => '/uploads/stories/112.jpg',
        'created' => '2014-06-13 07:43:18',
        'modified' => '2014-06-13 07:43:18',
        'created_by' => '1',
        'original' => null,
        'tags' => ''
    ),
    'StoryChapter' => array(),
    'StoryUser' => array(),
    'StoryGroup' => array(),
    'Favorite' => array(),
    'Tag' => array()
)
```

)

I want the find function to order only the StoryChapter by created desc without affecting the order of the found stories .

I hope you understand what I mean .

Thank you

Comment: Put an `ORDER BY` in the `find` method.

Comment: I don't want to order the stories but only the storychapters which belongs to the stories

Comment: You can order by more than one field/ column.

Comment: I can only order by fields from story table not story_chapter fields..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the order in the hasMany array in the Story model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'StoryChapter' => array(
        'className' => 'StoryChapter',
        'foreignKey' => 'story_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => 'created ASC',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
```